# Configure Mongodb for Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have a nodejs app which connects to Mongodb installed locally with the code :

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var Server = mongo.Server,
Db = mongo.Db,
BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('clients', server, {safe:false});

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to 'clients' database");
        db.collection('clients', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
        if (err) {
                console.log("The 'clients' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
            populateDB();
            }
        });
    }
});

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    db.collection('clients', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
};
```

Now I want to move this code to Heroku. According to Heroku, my code should look something like :

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
  process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
  'mongodb://localhost/mydb';

mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
  db.collection('mydocs', function(er, collection) {
    collection.insert({'mykey': 'myvalue'}, {safe: true}, function(er,rs) {
    });
  });
});
```

I can't seem to figure out how to restructure my code for it to work on Heroku.

Comment: Follow the [getting-started-with-nodejs-using-mongodb](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#using-mongodb) article on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be on heroku?

You could keep your code on Heroku, easily configure a free Mongodb instance/datasource in Mongolab ( https://mongolab.com/products/pricing/ ) and adjust your code to connect to the free Mongodb instance on Mongolab:

mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@dfs12345.mongolab.com:56789/dbname

Ref: http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/

Comment: so I should replace 'localhost' in my code with the mongolab url right ?

Comment: I have no idea where you got your 'mongodb' driver from, but this is the documentation for the 'mongodb' driver that I found: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Comment: @Mohit-Athwani Having said that: Look at the Heroku code: 'mongodb://localhost/mydb' - you could easily customize it for that URL. As for your current code, I would replace the 'localhost' parameter of Server() with mongodb://user:dbpassword@dfs12345.mongolab.com, the '27017' parameter of Server() with 57789, you are probably keeping 'clients' as your database name. Note that when you are creating/porting your Mongodb data to Mongolab and registering yourself with them as a user, you will be assigned your own URL and access port plus you will be choosing your own username and password